# Show/Hide Circle when dbClick on the marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have already made web searches before asking this question.

I am currently drawing a circle when I double-click on my marker whith this function:

```
  function drawRadius(marker, map){
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function () {
           circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            fillColor : '#3333FF',
            fillOpacity : 0.5,
            radius : 10000,
            strokeColor : '#BBD8E9',
            strokeOpacity : 0.9,
            strokeWeight : 2
          });
          circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
      });       
  }
```

Here is the full code : http://jsfiddle.net/rjhzq/1/

The problem is that I want to show or hide the circle when I double click on the marker.

I have already try 
`if (circle!=null){circle.setMap(null);}`

But the problem is that i call the function drawCircle right after creating the marker.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a variable to your marker to keep a reference of your `circle` being added to it.
Something like:

```
// If your marker has a circle, remove it and remove the reference to it.
if (marker.circle) {
    marker.circle.setMap(null);
    marker.circle = null;
    return;
}
circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    fillColor: '#3333FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 10000,
    strokeColor: '#BBD8E9',
    strokeOpacity: 0.9,
    strokeWeight: 2
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
marker.circle = circle; // Add circle to marker as reference
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjhzq/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot putvande for your help!